# How to check if a value already exists in SQL Server CE database

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am developing an application in C# using SQL Server Compact database

My problem is how to avoid duplicate entries in tables. For example, one student name is 'Praveen', it shouldn't accept another record with that same name.

Comment: you could add constraints / Indexes, Primary Key etc... if not then you would have to write your own code and or sql statement and the easiest one that I can think of right now would be to run a IF Exist or if Inserting use IN or NOT IN there are so many ways to do this to avoid duplicates.. but I would start at the Database end first and set up some Keys ie First Name + Last Name + SSN for example... because First names and last names are not truly unique

Comment: Hope this VB.net code snippet helps you (you may just 'translate it' http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/VB/Visual-Basic-Code-Snippet-Check-Record-Exists-in-SQL-Server-Database.html

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Make student name a unique key.

Comment: What if there is more than one student with the same name..I think the key should be on Students Name + some other unique Key or combination of Keys